# Beginner issues with PowerCLI, Multiple arrays, for loops

Tags: arrays, powershell, for-loop, powercli, import-csv

I've been Googling around all day and I can't seem to crack this nut. I've got a csv from RVTools with the VM name and the VLAN listed (*Column names VM & Network*) , my goal is to have PowerCLI change the VLAN in vCenter to match the VLAN in the CSV.

I first did it the hard way for our test environment, by putting both columns into their own separate array

```
$HadesList = "C:\Users\-user-\Desktop\test.csv"
$TestList = Import-CSV $HadesList
$result = ForEach($Line in $TestList) { $Line.VM }
$result2 = ForEach($Line2 in $TestList) {  $Line2.Network  }

    get-vm $result[0] | Get-NetworkAdapter | Set-NetworkAdapter -NetworkName $result2[0] -Confirm:$false
...manually changing the numbers...
    get-vm $result[24] | Get-NetworkAdapter | Set-NetworkAdapter -NetworkName $result2[24] -Confirm:$false
```

Which worked fine in the testlab, since it was only 25 VMs. But when we go to do this change in production, I wanted something more concise. I searched around and found someone doing for loops that will return data, so I tried to use it to change the network adapter, but it errored out:

```
$VMData = Import-CSV C:\Users\-user-\Desktop\test.csv
  for ($i=0; $i -lt $VMData.count; $i++){    
Get-VM $VMData.VM[$i] | Get-NetworkAdapter | Set-NetworkAdapter -NetworkName $VMData.Network[$i] -Confirm:$false
}
```

> Set-NetworkAdapter : 2/24/2020 2:15:41 PM Set-NetworkAdapter      Cannot find the environment browser for VMHost with Id: 'HostSystem-host-14'.
>   At line:2 char:46
>   + ... rkAdapter | Set-NetworkAdapter -NetworkName $VMData.Network[$i] -Conf ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (HostSystem-host-14:String) [Set-NetworkAdapter], ViError
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Client20_VmHostServiceImpl_TryGetHostEnvironmentBrowser_EnvironmentBrowserNotFound,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.VirtualDevice.SetNetworkAdapter

Is there anything that could make something like this work? I've been beating my head against this all day and I can't even figure out a way to phrase it to get better search results.

Comment: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/419666

According to this thread, the error `...Cannot find the environment browser for VMHost with Id: 'HostSystem-host-14'...` is a known bug and has no resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the script from Kyle on a different vCenter and it worked perfectly. The odd part is I can't find the difference in PowerCLI between the two

Errors out:

- PowerCLI C:> Get-PowerCLIVersion
- PowerCLI Version
- VMware PowerCLI 6.5 Release 1 build 4624819
- Component Versions
- VMware Cis Core PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4624453
- VMware VimAutomation Core PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4624450
- VMWare ImageBuilder PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4561891
- VMWare AutoDeploy PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4561891
- VMware Vds PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4624695
- VMware Cloud PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4624821
- VMware HA PowerCLI Component 6.0 build 4525225
- VMware HorizonView PowerCLI Component 7.0.2 build 4596620
- VMware Licensing PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4624822
- VMware PCloud PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4624825
- VMware Storage PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4624820
- VMware vROps PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4624824
- VMware vSphere Update Manager PowerCLI 6.5 build 4540462

Works perfectly:

- PowerCLI Version
- VMware PowerCLI 6.5 Release 1 build 4624819
- Component Versions
- VMware Cis Core PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4624453
- VMware VimAutomation Core PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4624450
- VMWare ImageBuilder PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4561891
- VMWare AutoDeploy PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4561891
- VMware Vds PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4624695
- VMware Cloud PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4624821
- VMware HA PowerCLI Component 6.0 build 4525225
- VMware HorizonView PowerCLI Component 7.0.2 build 4596620
- VMware Licensing PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4624822
- VMware PCloud PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4624825
- VMware Storage PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4624820
- VMware vROps PowerCLI Component 6.5 build 4624824
- VMware vSphere Update Manager PowerCLI 6.5 build 4540462

They're both on vSphere Client version 6.7.0.20000 so I really can't point to any reason it fails on one not the other

Answer (score 0):

I think you could probably consolidate it down to looping through the variable of the imported CSV with a named variable for each line.

Example:

```
$VMData = Import-CSV C:\Users\-user-\Desktop\test.csv
foreach ($line in $VMData){
   Get-VM $line.VM | Get-NetworkAdapter | Set-NetworkAdapter -NetworkName $line.Network -Confirm:$false
}
```

Comment: That is a quality consolidation! However, I still get the error in my original post 
`...Cannot find the environment browser for VMHost with Id: 'HostSystem-host-14'...`

When I remove the *Set-NetworkAdapter* part, it pulls the VM's networks as it should. It must be something to do with the .csv import, because I can't imagine there should be any difference between 
`get-vm $result[23] | Get-NetworkAdapter | Set-NetworkAdapter -NetworkName $result2[23] -Confirm:$false`
and
`Get-VM $line.VM | Get-NetworkAdapter | Set-NetworkAdapter -NetworkName $line.Network -Confirm:$false`